# Qt and Google Earth API

Tags: qt, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, qt4.8

Is it possible to develop an application in Qt, using Google Earth?

For example, I want to show the earth (as in google earth) as a sphere via QtGL in my application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is obvious that you can use google earth api with Qt. And I want to share a secret(!!!). Google earth is developed with Qt. :D

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/kml-support-com-api/browse_thread/thread/743601cce38d4a86?pli=1) you can find some people discussing about google earth and Qt. [Here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23680-Google-Maps-API-and-Qt-4-desktop-app-integration) is some anothe example.

Comment: Google Earth API was removed in 2015. No signs of use of Google Earth in Qt anymore

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at the GE Api [here](https://developers.google.com/earth/). There is a discussion on embedding Google Earth in a Qt Window [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/kml-support-com-api/dDYBzOONSoY).

If what you are trying to do is reinvent an application similar to Google Earth, then the process is much more complicated. As you mention you would have to render a 3D globe using the OpenGL widget. I don't really see why you would do that if you can just embed GE in your application.

Comment: Google Earth API is deprecated in 2015