# Embed Google Earth in desktop applications instead of website. Is QT a real option?

Tags: c++, qt, embed, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have in mind to develop a desktop application that simulates a satellite camera orbiting the earth. I would like to use Google Earth in a desktop application instead of embedding it in a website. Apparently the only option that the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/#introduction) offers is for web pages

I read in a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740982/qt-and-google-earth-api) that using QT is possible to embed Google Earth in desktop applications, however most of the links in the referred websites are broken so a lot of information about the topic is missing. Furthermore all the information I found is very old.

Could anyone suggest me a method to embed Google Earth in desktop applications? I have some experience with C++, ADA and Visual Basic but no idea of QT.

Comment: You can use the Qt's HTML API and Webkit to show the Google Maps in a webview. When loading the page, set your html/javascript to load the plugin. Of course, you'll have to have both Google Earth and the plugin installed (correctly and in the place that Qt/WebKit searches for plugins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedding Google Earth in a desktop application involves working with the [Google Earth Plugin](https://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html), a browser extension controlled by a JavaScript API. There are at least two examples ([here](https://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/) and [here](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/desktop-embedded/index.html)) written in C#. As for C++, the easiest way would be using a framework which can open a "browser window", [Qt for example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebkitwidgets-index.html). An alternative to Qt is the [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), which is a C++ library to embed the Chromium engine in desktop applications.